# Collapse issue to create dynamic form not insert data second collapse in php

Tags: php

I have issue in ajax
Set A add data in database proper but problem is set B form not get value of $("#id").Val(); value
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1RpA.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmIaZ.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O41pH.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTL5C.png

please see image n give any solution

```html
 <div class='accordion'>
        <div class='card'><button type='button' class='btn btn-link' data-toggle="collapse" id = "<?php echo $row1["set_id"]; ?>" data-target="#collapseExample<?php echo $row1["set_id"]; ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><?php echo $row1["set_name"]; ?></button></div>
                <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample<?php echo $row1["set_id"]; ?>">
                     <div class="card card-body">
                          <form  action ="upload.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                               <div class="form-group">
                                      <h4 style="color:blue"><?php echo $row1["set_name"];?></h4><br>
                                         <h4>Add Question</h4><br>
                                            <label for="Question">Question</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-12" id="quest" name="question" placeholder="Question">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                         <label>Options</label>
                                            <div class="row">
                                              <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option1" name="option1" id="option1"></div>
                                              <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option2" name="option2" id ="option2"></div>
                                              <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option3" name="option3" id="option3"></div>
                                              <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option4" name="option4" id="option4"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <label>Answer</label>
                                             <select id="answer" name="answer" class="form-control"  style="width: 120px;">
                                                    <option>1</option>
                                                    <option>2</option>
                                                    <option>3</option>
                                                    <option>4</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <br>
                                                <label>Explanation PDF</label>
                                                <br>
                                                 <label style="color:blue;">File Upload</label><br>
                                                 <input type="file" id="file" name="file" /> 
                
                                            </div>
                                           <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="flaticon-cancel-12"></i>Discard</button>
                                            <button>Save</button>
                                            <br>
                                            <div id="autoSave" width="300px"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                               </form>
                               <script>
                                   $("form").submit(function(e){
                                             e.preventDefault();
                                              var form_data = $(this).serialize();
                                             
                                             $.post(
                                                 
                                                 'upload.php',
                                                 {
                                                     question:$('#quest').val(),
                                                     option1:$('#option1').val(),
                                                     option2:$('#option2').val(),
                                                     option3:$('#option3').val(),
                                                     option4:$('#option4').val(),
                                                     answer:$('#answer').val()
                                                     
                                                  },
                                                 
                                                 function(result){
                                                     console.log(result);
                                                     if(result == "success"){
                                                         $("result").html("Save");
                                                     }
                                                     else{
                                                         $("result").html("Error");
                                                     }
                                                     
                                                 }
                                                 
                                                 )
                                                 return false; 
                                         })
                                     
                               </script>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
```

problem is Set A easily insert data in database but set B is same dynamic form value insert is null value to insert in database

Comment: You need to post code here, not images. The question description also is very unclear, reads like this is a homework question that was just copy and pasted here.

Comment: Could you please at least remove the commented elements from that code?